# How can I have multiple fields with the same taxonomy on Drupal's node creation form?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

My designers want to use the same taxonomy for three different purposes. On the node creation form we'd have three different fields where you're choosing from the same set of terms. Ideally, one field would enforce a single choice (and be hierarchical), and the others would allow multiple choices with tags. Any thoughts about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the CCK module with the Content Taxonomy module to add taxonomy fields to a custom content type used by the nodes. Relevant links:

http://drupal.org/project/cck and http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy

Comment: Ah! content_taxonomy! I figured there was something. Thanks!